# How to pass a lot of images to jquery ui tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jquery UI tooltip. Here's a usage.

```
<a href="#" title="Enter Text Here" data-imgurl="Image-URL" class="fiwTooltip">Aumkar Thakur</a>
```

And here is JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fiwTooltip').hover(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');  //Getting Title Text
        var imgurl = $(this).attr('data-imgurl'); // Getting Image URL
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<div class="tooltip"><p class="txttooltip">'+title+'</p><img src="'+imgurl+'" class="imgtooltip"/>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

Everything works fine with a single image, but what if I want to add not only one image to ***data-imgurl="Image-URL"*** (i have collection of user avatars and I need to pass them all to one tooltip). How can I solve my problem?

Comment: give us an example of how the data will be formatted if there are multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, learn to use references. 
Search an object once, then use the reference. It speeds up your scripts and makes phones less hot.

I'm assuming the images will be seperated by ;. Therefore the below script, based on your script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fiwTooltip').hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var title = $this.attr('title');  //Getting Title Text
        var imgurl = $this.attr('data-imgurl'); // Getting Image URL
  
        $this.data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        var $img = $('<img class="imgtooltip">');
        var $text = $('<p class="txttooltip"></p>');
        $text.text(title);
        var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip"></div>');
        $tooltip.append($text);
        
        var split = imgurl.split(';');
  
        for(var c=0;c<split.length;c++) { 
          var clone = $img.clone();
          clone.attr('src',split[c]);
          $tooltip.append(clone);
        }
  
        $tooltip.appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('tipText'));
        
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="Enter Text Here" data-imgurl="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1;https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1" class="fiwTooltip">Tschallacka 2</a>

<a href="#" title="Enter Text Here" data-imgurl="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1" class="fiwTooltip">Tschallacka 1</a>

<a href="#" title="Enter Text Here" data-imgurl="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1;https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1;https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxvn.png?s=64&g=1" class="fiwTooltip">Tschallacka 3</a>
```